# Net angular motion of a body in two cases

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, rotation, angular-velocity

So here I have two questions and both have nearly the same structure but the method used for both of them is different, not method exactly but formula. So here is the first question,[image]

So here is the solution to the problem,

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the solution,

The net motion is considered to be the combination of spin and orbital motion of the body and I agree with this,

In the solution as well the net angular velocity is $Ω$ and thus the spin angular motion is defined as $ω_s= Ωcos(α)$ and similarly, $ω_o= Ωsin(α)$.

Now here is the second question, [image]

And here is the solution to this question,
[image]

The conditions are still the same,

But in this case, while solving the question, $Ω= ω_scos(θ)$ and $ω_o=  ω_ssin(θ)$, Now I don't know why this is true, like how can be the net motion depicted as a component of one of it is resolved component, for example, in a $3-4-5$ triangle, we can write, $4=5cos(37^o)$ but not $5=4cos(37^o)$ but in this case, it is written like the latter one. Could someone explain why is this true for this case?

Now I could have discarded the solution but the answer to the option is found to be correct in this way only, so that means this method is right but I don't know why?

So it would be helpful if someone could explain to me why is this true?

Thank you in advance...